# jqgrid: show all rows on empty search

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have jqGrid with [single search](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asinge_searching#options) enabled. Is it possible to show all rows when search string is empty? In my situation there will be no empty fields, so I don't need possibility to search by empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can just switch `search` options of jqGrid to `false` if the data for searching are empty. You can use `onSearch` callback of [searching options](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asinge_searching#options). The code example of the callback will be the following:

```
onSearch: function () {
    var $self = $(this),
        postData = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData");
    if (postData.searchString === "") {
        $self.jqGrid("setGridParam", {search: false});
    }
}
```